# Formatting database prior to running `debug` command in psiTurk shell?

Tags: mysql, server

I have a mysql database called `participants` with a table called `turkdemo` in it...the`database_url` string and `table_name` string are set to the proper "http://:@127.0.0.1:3306/participants" and "turkdemo".

- I'll start the mysql server:
  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`
- open psiTurk, start the server, then debug:

`psiturk`

`server on`

`debug`

Next, the shell outputs that it's launching a browser window...it does and it says

"**Internal Server Error**
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

The last line of server.log: (here's the [full log entry](http://pastebin.com/yLY33ANa))

`OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'turkdemo.uniqueid' in 'field list'") 'SELECT count(*) AS count_1 \nFROM (SELECT turkdemo.uniqueid AS turkdemo_uniqueid, turkdemo.assignmentid AS turkdemo_assignmentid, turkdemo.workerid AS turkdemo_workerid, turkdemo.hitid AS turkdemo_hitid, turkdemo.ipaddress AS turkdemo_ipaddress, turkdemo.browser AS turkdemo_browser, turkdemo.platform AS turkdemo_platform, turkdemo.language AS turkdemo_language, turkdemo.cond AS turkdemo_cond, turkdemo.counterbalance AS turkdemo_counterbalance, turkdemo.codeversion AS turkdemo_codeversion, turkdemo.beginhit AS turkdemo_beginhit, turkdemo.beginexp AS turkdemo_beginexp, turkdemo.endhit AS turkdemo_endhit, turkdemo.bonus AS turkdemo_bonus, turkdemo.status AS turkdemo_status, turkdemo.datastring AS turkdemo_datastring \nFROM turkdemo \nWHERE turkdemo.assignmentid != %s AND turkdemo.workerid = %s) AS anon_1' (u'debug8TBWSM', u'debugJ4DKWD')`

I'm not really sure what's going on here. Looking at the error, it seems that there are missing fields in the `tabledemo` table. I was assuming that psiTurk will do all the proper SELECT and INSERT stuff on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are missing field in the tabledemo table it will fail because the schema is not correctly aligned.  You can just delete 'tabledemo' from your SQL database and it will automatically re-create it with the right schema the first time you run psiturk in that experiment folder.